# Typing menu data

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to type menu data

```js
type MenuItem = { title: string; href: string }

type SubMenu = { title: string; submenu: MenuItem[] }
```

Creating menu like:

```js
const menu: (MenuItem | SubMenu)[] = [
    { title: "", href: "" },
    { title: "", href: "" },
    {
        title: "",
        submenu: [
            { title: "", href: "" },
            { title: "", href: "" },
            { title: "", href: "" },
        ],
    },
]
```

Wondering why TypeScript does't report error when I add this to the menu array:

```js
{
        title: "",
        href: "",
        submenu: [
            { title: "", href: "" },
            { title: "", href: "" },
            { title: "", href: "" },
        ],
    },
```

Comment: [Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)